# How do I craw hyperlinks from a website using RVEST?

Tags: r, web-crawler, rvest

I'm having trouble trying to crawl all link urls from a news website.

https://www.lightreading.com/archives.asp?section_id=120&piddl_month=12&piddl_year=2020

This is the site link and I'm trying to crawl all hyperlink URLs on the article titles.
Below is the code I came up with - thinking '.card-title' is a class, and 'href' an attribute,

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(readr)

url <- paste('https://www.lightreading.com/archives.asp?section_id=120&piddl_month=12&piddl_year=2020')

data_url <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes('.card-title') %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  html_text()
```

Error in UseMethod("xml_text") :
no applicable method for 'xml_text' applied to an object of class "character"

This is the error message I get. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you already have a character vector, not a document/node/nodeset, returned by:

```
read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes('.card-title') %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

The additional hml node method call you try, `html_text()`,  after this, is therefore throwing the error. Just remove that final call and leave as:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(readr)

url <- paste('https://www.lightreading.com/archives.asp?section_id=120&piddl_month=12&piddl_year=2020')

data_url <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes('.card-title') %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

---

From [documentation](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/reference/html_text.html):

> html_text() extracts text inside a node

It is expected to be called on:

> Arguments: `x`     A document, node, or node set.